# AVAudioEnvironmentNode crashes when changing its renderingAlgorithm in background mode

Tags: audiounit

I am using AVAudioEnvironmentNode for a simple app. It plays well when the application is on the screen or the device is not idle, but when the device goes idle and renderingAlgorithm is changing, the audio changes into a loud noise and it stops playing. 
I think that is something with the idle state of the device. Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: What language (Swift, C, Objective C)?  How are you changing your rendering algorithm (show your code)?  Is your app handling audio session notifications the correct number of samples?

Comment: Swift, and I am using ( just for testing), a delayed action. If you mean interruption handling or engine change, no It does not happen. Could you explain the last one a little bit more, I am kinda newbie in this area. Thank you.